# How to create a reusable screen recording thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, mp4

I created a reusable screen recording thread by `cv2`. However, my computer crashed when I stop and restart this thread. Sometimes, it works but the video `MP4` file crashed

Background:
for my code ,there is a main thread, it will call `Video_Record.start_recording` to record video until main thread calls `Video_Record.stop_recording`. The main thread can reuse this video thread and create new video anytime.

is there any suggestion to improve my code? I am thinking about the reason why my computer crashed is memory leak. I am not sure `daemon` thread is ok or not.

```
    class Video_Record(threading.Thread):    
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
            self.running = True  # must be true
            self.recording_running = False
            self.fps = 20
            self.prev = 0
            self.out = None
            self.screen_size = tuple(pyautogui.size())
            # self.screen_size=(1920,1080)
    
        def run(self):
            while self.running:
                while self.recording_running:
                    try:
                        img = pyautogui.screenshot()
                        self.prev = time.time()
                        frame = np.array(img)
                        frame = cv2.resize(frame, self.screen_size)
                        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        self.out.write(frame)
                        # cv2.imshow("screen recorder",frame)   # show screen recorder
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error('[MAIN] out={}'.format(self.out))
                        traceback.print_exc()
                        write_log(logpath=Processlogpath, company_name='RPA', function_name='Main RPA Trigger',
                                  status='Fail', exception=e, spec_msg="video record,path={}".format(self.video_path))
                    # if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord("q"):
                    #     break
    
        def stop_recording(self):
            try:
                self.recording_running = False
                self.out.release()
                self.out = None
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                logger.info('[MAIN] video record end')
                write_log(logpath=Processlogpath, company_name='RPA', function_name='Main RPA Trigger',
                          status='Success', spec_msg="video record success")
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
    
        def start_recording(self, video_name=r'output'):
            try:
                if self.running:
                    logger.info('[MAIN] video record start')
                    if self.out == None:
                        #self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
                        # self.video_path = "D:\\Desktop\\New folder\\{}-output3.avi".format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
                        self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
                        if production_platform:
                            self.video_path = "H:\\activity\\video_record\\{}-{}.mp4".format(
                                video_name, time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
                        else:
                            self.video_path = "H:\\RPA\\activity\\video_record\\{}-{}.mp4".format(
                                video_name, time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
                        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(
                            self.video_path, self.fourcc, self.fps, (self.screen_size))
                    self.recording_running = True
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
    
        def stop(self):
            """
            pause the thread
            """
            self.running = False
    
        def resume(self):
            """
            resume the thread
            """
            self.running = True
```

Comment: please elaborate on "my computer crashed". how much did it crash? how much did it _not_ crash?

Comment: My computer is down and i need to restart it